# Where can we get alternative of Firefox SDK commands in web extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

We have ADD-ON which support till Firefox version 56. We are upgrading the Add-On to web extension and finding the alternative for the sdk/test command.

Comment: WebExtensions platform is less capable so there may be no alternative. Describe the specific features to make your question answerable.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.